# Network Flow Update Values

Tags: algorithm, math, network-flow

I am practicing Algorithms problems from my book and came across this one:

> You are given a directed network G with n nodes and m edges, a source s, a sink t and a maximum flow f from s to t. Assuming that the capacity of every edge is a positive integer, describe an O(m + n) time algorithm for updating the flow f in each of the following two cases.
>
> (i)  The capacity of edge e increases by 1.
>
> (ii) The capacity of edge e decreases by 1.

It seems like it would be as simple as walking through the network flow edges and adjusting flows, but I do not think it is really that simple.  Wikipedia only give algorithms that are O(n^2 m) or O(n m^2).  Any help or thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a solution [here](http://www.csc.kth.se/utbildning/kth/kurser/DD2354/algokomp10/Ovningar/Exercise5_Sol.pdf).

Suppose e is an edge between u and v.

### Increased capacity

The idea for increasing the capacity is to simply do a DFS in the residual flow graph for a path from s to t.

### Decreased capacity

If the edge is unsed in the maximum flow then you are done.

Otherwise, the idea is to see if there is an alternative path from u to v in the residual flow graph.  This takes O(n+m).  If found, then you can increase the maximum flow by 1.

Otherwise, you need to decrease the flow.  You do this by finding a path from u to s along which the flow can increase by 1, and a path from t to v along which the flow can increase by 1.
(The increases are in a reverse direction so this reduces the flow from s to t).